# In swift I want to check if the number which I passed as a parameter to the function is in the array ( which aslo I passed as a parameter)

Tags: arrays, swift, where-clause, contains, func

```
func check (num: Int, arr: Array<Any>) -> Bool {
    if arr.contains(where: num) {
        return true
    }
}
check(num: 7, arr: [1, 4, 7, 25, 99])
```

// eror: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool'

Comment: `func check(num: Int, arr: Array<Int>) -> Bool { return arr.contains(num) }`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing lot of incorrect coding in the above question. So it is better to take a look at here -> [Functions in Swit](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html).

1. when u are passing an array as a parameter u should use `[DataTpye]` signature.
2. The method use to check if an element is in an array is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/contains(_:)) **not** [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/contains(where:)).
3. Your whole function should return a boolean value not only the if part.

Corrected version

```
func check (num: Int, arr: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return arr.contains(num)
}
```

```
print(check(num: 7, arr: [1, 4, 7, 25, 99])) // true
```